# A basic question on distribution function and stieljes integral

Tags: probability-theory

Is it true that

$$\int_{\Bbb R} G(x)dF(x) + \int_{\Bbb R} F(y)dG(y) = 1$$

where $F$ and $G$ are distribution functions of $X$ and $Y$ such that both have no common jump points i.e. $P(X=Y) = 0$ ? How to prove it ? I am unfamiliar with Stieljes integral

Comment: You can prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the first integral is $\Pr(Y \leq X)$ and the second one is $\Pr(X \leq Y)$.

Comment: @Siméon: without independence I have been asked to prove it.

Comment: One can choose X and Y independent with the proper CDFs--but why repost the same question as a duplicate?